# Value of $x$, and decomposition of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

If we have $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ as a set of orthonormal nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $x$ an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then what are the values of $c_k$, for $k = 1,2,\ldots,n$

if $\displaystyle x=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k v_k\ {}$?

This is a numerical analysis question but is induction helpful in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you meant $x=\sum_{k=1}^n c_kv_k$, then $c_k = (x|v_k)$.

Proof : the $v_k$'s form a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, as they are n linearly independant vectors.

therefore the $c_k$'s exist. $x=\sum_{k=1}^n c_kv_k$. Using the scalar product :

$$(x|v_i)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_kv_k{\Huge |}v_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k(v_k|v_i) = c_i \|v_i\|^2=c_i$$

using both the fact that $\|v_i\|=1$ and $(v_k|v_i)=0$ for $i\neq k$.

Comment: What does the (X|vi notation mean)? I dont understand the slash. Thanks

Comment: it is the dot product (or scalar product). $(a|b)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$, where the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are coordinates of $a$ and $b$ in the canonical basis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product. Orthogonality in $\mathbb R^n$ is defined by $(a|b)=0$